# Is there a way to forcefully show browser's default "Leaving site" confirmation dialog?

Tags: javascript, browser

When implementing "loose unsaved changes" confirmation dialogs you usually use `window.onbeforeunload` to display **default prompt** to the user like

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', e => {
  if (this.mustPromptUser()) {
    e.returnValue = '';
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

That prompt varies accross browsers - it has different message and buttons labels. Moreover, it is different when user refreshes page and navigating to a different URL.

Now, having Angular app internal routing has to be taken into account as well. That is doe via guards. However, what I would like to do, is to use the exact same browser's default dialogs. Is there a way to show that default confirmation prompts?

If not, I will have to hardcode message and button labels for Chrome,FF,IE etc and make it platform sensitive - which I don't want to do obviously.

Comment: Each browser has a different *default prompt*. Which one is the *default* for you?

Comment: Change the architecture, instead of asking user to save changes, save the data temporarily automatically. When the user visits the page again, ask them if the last modifications should be saved permanently.

Comment: @Lain That's the point -- they want to find out what the browser's default is, so they can generate it in their dialog.

Comment: @Barmar thats almost the case - I just would like to be able to invoke the exact same dialogs that browser is displaying to the user  (that is not customizable)- just like you would do with `window.confirm`

Comment: @Lain its not default to me - its default to the browser. When you use provided snippet, prompt will be displayed on navigation or f5 (different in both cases). That confirmation dialog cannot be customized nor bypassed - therefore I would like to use it in different part of the app to stay consistent (and have exactly the same set of notifications)

Comment: It is possible that it is impossible ... just like customization of `window.confirm` dialogs and the default `onbeforeunload` dialogs ...

Comment: `beforeunload/unload` events are not even fired in all browsers, so, it's more impossible.

Comment: I also advise to take the extra step and either code it yourself to have full control over what is happening or like Teemu wrote, change your approach of it. It usually pays out in the long run.

Comment: @JavaScript I dont have (nor you) controll over confirmations in onbeforeunload.

Comment: Exactly. So better ues a way which you can actually control.

Comment: In this "unload" scenario I can't anyway. Its biz requirement, nothing I can do about it (and chrome - which is the only required target browser supports that) Thanks.